# Why is one array affected by changes I make to another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str=str.toLowerCase();
  str=str.split("");
  var evilstr=str;
  var counter = [];
  for (i=0;i<150;i++) {
  counter.push(evilstr.findIndex(function(character){    
    return character===" ";

  }));
    evilstr[i]="x";
  }
     return str;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

and it produces this result:

```
'['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x',...'
```

Why is `str` affected at all by the for loop? After I split it into separate characters, I don't change it at all, do I?

Comment: `evilstr=str` doesn't make a new copy of `str`.

Comment: yes, it does. Primitives are always stored as copies.

Comment: but str=str.split....

Comment: @shadymoses but it's not a primitive, it's an array! (see third line!)

Comment: ha! my bad. I totally glazed over the top two lines of the function.

Comment: `var evilstr=str.slice();`

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the value of `str`. Just set ```evilstr`` to the array you want to generate from the input string:

```
var evilstr = str.toLowerCase().split('')
```

Then you need to actually return `evilstr` instead of ```str``.

```
return evilStr.join('')
```

Alternatively, you don't create `evilStr` at all:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].slice(1); 
  }
  return str.join(' ');
}
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

But to actually answer your question: arrays and objects in javascript are always stored by reference, unless you specifically create a new one.

```
// this creates a new array with 4 items
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
// this creates a new variable that points to the array referenced in arr
var arr2 = arr
// add a value to arr2
arr2.push(5)
// check the value of arr
console.log(arr) /// shows [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So when you changed the value of `str` to be an array and then made `evilStr` point to that array, any changes you made to `evilStr` are made to `str` as well.

Comment: Thnaks, so can I create an Object that copies the properties of another, but is from then on not linked to that object in any way?

Comment: Yes, and that can be done a number of ways. For example, you can use ```.slice()``` to get a copy of an array, like ```someArray.slice()```. You can use ```Object.assign``` to merge objects, and if you make the first object an empty literal you'll get a brand new object, eg ```Object.assign({}, someObj, someOtherObject)```